# Remove white space from left & right side of header image

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm currently in the process of setting up my blog, and I am having difficulty formatting the header in the way I had planned.

[Here is my site](http://almostallison.com). As you can see, their is extra space on the sides of the header. My goal would be to remove the space, so that the floral pattern is flush with the content box or whatever you call it.

I've gone through my theme's CSS multiple times, and have changed the margins, widths, and paddings on everything and anything possibly associated with the header image, but have had zero luck. Is their something I'm missing?

My blog is hosted through Wordpress and my parent theme is from the Genesis Framework.

Here is the CSS for the header image:

```
/*
Site Header
--------------------------------------------- */

.audrie .site-header {
    background-position: center;
    padding:0px 0;
        width:100%;
}

/* Title Area
--------------------------------------------- */

.title-area {
    padding: 0px 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.title-area h1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.title-area p {
    margin: 0;
}

.header-image .title-area {
    padding: 0;
        width:100%;
}

.site-title,
.site-title a {
    font-size: 64px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.site-title a,
.site-title a:hover {
    color: #747474;
}

.site-description {
    color: #808080;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: none;
}

/* Full width header, no widgets */

.header-full-width .title-area,
.header-full-width .site-title {
    width: 100%;
}

.header-image .site-description,
.header-image .site-title a {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}

/* Logo, hide text */

.header-image .site-header {
    background-position: center !important;
    background-size: 1000px 200px !important;
    padding: 0;
margin-top:-90px;
padding-bottom:30px;
}

.header-image .site-title a {
    float: none;
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Widget Area
--------------------------------------------- */

.site-header .widget-area {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    width: 720px;
}

.header-image .site-header .widget-area {
    padding: 0px 0;
}

.site-header .search-form {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 22px;
}
```

Any help or guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You want the floral image to match the pink bar's width, or to fill the entire white background?

Comment: To match the pink bar, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
.site-container{
padding: 0
}

.header-image .site-header{
background-size: 1100px 200px !important;
}

.site-inner{
padding: 36px;
}
```

maybe some !important is needed and check the responsiv-behavior..

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! However, it stretched the image, which I figured it would, but when I went to upload and replace it with one of a larger size (1100px), wordpress's photo upload automatically crops the image, which then reverts it back to a smaller size, thus making it look stretched out and blurry. Any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Your header (`.site-header`) has a fixed background size of:

```
background-size: 1000px 200px !important;
```

But your `.site-container` div has a max width of 1100px, witch makes your image smaller than the rest. Instead, let it be responsive, as in:

```
background-size: 100% auto !important;
/*Assuming you have a reason for "!important" */
```

Comment: Just to clarify, am I changing the width properties of the .site-container, or the .site-header?

Comment: You are changing the width property of the background image of `.site-header`

Answer (score 1):

`.site-container` has a 36px horizontal padding which is causing the whitespace around your header. If you add:

```
.site-container {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

your horizontal whitespace will disappear, but you'll also need to add:

```
header {
  background-size: 1100px 200px !important
}
```

to get the top image to span full width.

Finally to clean it up I'd add:

```
.site-inner{
  padding-left: 36px;
  padding-right: 36px;
}
```

so your text has some room on the sides.

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, this did not seem to work. Even though I changed the padding-left & right to 0px, it was still showing the whitespace, even after applying the rest of your suggestions. Strange.